# Modify Newton's gravity to cure the action at a distance

Tags: newtonian-gravity, field-theory, specific-reference, point-particles, modified-gravity

Take a bunch of particles (can be point particles) at ${\bf{x}}_i(t)$ and of mass $m_i>0$.
The gravitational field is defined by the Poisson equation
$$
\nabla^2 \Phi({\bf{x}},t) = 4 \pi G \rho({\bf{x}},t)=4 \pi G\sum_i m_i \delta({\bf{x}}-{\bf{x}}_i(t))
$$
Now, this creates a coupling between the point particles, but it is *not* a "dynamical" coupling: given the mass configuration $\rho({\bf{x}},t)$ the field $\Phi$ is determined everywhere instantaneously. This is because the Poisson equation does not contain any temporal derivative: $\Phi({\bf{x}},t)$ is not a dynamical object. Strictly speaking, $\Phi({\bf{x}},t)$ is not even needed and we may work directly with the force and the set of ordinary differential equations $m_i \ddot{{\bf x}}_i =  {{\bf F}}_i$.

I wonder if the following modification of Newton's gravity has ever been taken into account (I guess so, as it looks quite natural): we promote $\Phi$ to the state of dynamical field by substituting the Laplacian with the [wave operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator):
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{c^2 \,  \partial t^2} \Phi({\bf{x}},t) -\nabla^2 \Phi({\bf{x}},t) = -4 \pi G \rho({\bf{x}},t)= - 4 \pi G\sum_i m_i \delta({\bf{x}}-{\bf{x}}_i(t))
$$
As $c\rightarrow \infty$ we recover Newton. Is there a natural action principle for the field $\Phi$ and the point masses degrees of freedom? In this way it should be possible to obtain the equation of motion for the masses: since we modified the Poisson equation now I am not sure that
it simply reads $  \ddot{{\bf x}}_i \propto -\nabla{\Phi}$.

Comment: Looks like it did precede GR: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_theories_of_gravitation#Nordstr%C3%B6m's_theories_of_gravitation

Comment: Super, thank you! it seems it's called Nordström's theory of gravitation. If you find good references (introductory) let me know, I will also search for that.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/692578/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87591/226902 . Also interesting but less related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/343123/226902